# Finding $k$ claws ($K_{1,3}$ bipartite graphs) in a graph?

Tags: graphs, randomized-algorithms, bipartite-matching, colorings

Usually questions deal with claw-free graphs, but suppose we are given a graph $G$ and there are $k$ vertex-disjoing claws in the graph, how can we derive a randomised algorithm using color coding to find them. My intuition is to approach this with $k$ colors, but not really sure how to start it. Could someone give me some hints and ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Also, I haven't thought this through properly yet, so take it with a _large_ grain of salt; perhaps using $4k$ colours is the key - so each claw is uniquely coloured.

Comment: hey, they are vertex-disjoint. 4k colors,hmmm, how does 4k colors give each claw a unique color?

Answer (score 2):

Finding vertex-disjoint copies of a subgraph $H$ in a graph $G$ is known as *Graph Packing*.

You could use [Divide and Color](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11917496_6) to find the claws in $O^*(4^k)$, also deterministically (look for Chen et al. construction of universal set for derandomization).